# Property or method "_" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im a capable react developer, but have inherited a vue.js project from another developer and have maintained it for several years now, unfortunately I haven't gone through much personal effort to learn vue as i should.

I have a strange error being thrown from using lodash, I believe it doesnt like my `_.debounce` call

###### Component:

```js
<script>
import _ from 'lodash'
import CostCodeField from '@/components/workdays/CostCodeField'

// ...
</script>

<template lang='html'>
  <!-- relevant code snippet -->
  <!-- ... -->
  <b-table class="charges-table is-fullwidth" :data="workday.charges" :striped="true" :mobile-cards="false" :row-class="chargeClass">
    <b-table-column label="Cost Code" width="260">
        <b-field expanded="expanded">
          <cost-code-field
            :value="props.row.cost_code.number" :disabled="timecard.is_submitted || locked || isLoading(props)"
            :job="props.row.job"
            @input="set($event, props.index, 'cost_code')"
            @change="_.debounce(submit(props.row, props.index), 100)"
          ></cost-code-field>
          <p class="control">
            <a
              class="button"
              @click="triggerCostCode(props.row, props.index)" :disabled="props.row.job.jd_job_number_id === undefined || timecard.is_submitted || isLoading(props)"
            >
              <b-icon icon="magnify"></b-icon>
            </a>
          </p>
        </b-field>
      </b-table-column>
      <!-- ... -->
  </b-table>
</template>
```

###### console.error

```bash
[Vue warn]: Property or method "_" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <ChargesTable> at src/components/workdays/ChargesTable.vue
       <BTabItem>
         <BTabs>
           <WorkdayListItem> at src/components/workdays/WorkdayListItem.vue
             <Timecard> at src/components/timecards/Timecard.vue
               <App> at src/App.vue
                 <Root> vue.esm.js:628
    VueJS 3
    change ChargesTable.vue:127
    VueJS 4
    setCode CostCodeField.vue:108
    VueJS 12
    mutations timecards.js:322
    mutations timecards.js:319
    wrappedMutationHandler vuex.esm.js:844
    commitIterator vuex.esm.js:466
    commit vuex.esm.js:465
    _withCommit vuex.esm.js:624
    commit vuex.esm.js:464
    boundCommit vuex.esm.js:409
    submit CostCodeLookup.vue:134
    submit CostCodeLookup.vue:16
    VueJS 33
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm._ is undefined"

found in

---> <CostCodeField> at src/components/workdays/CostCodeField.vue
       <BField>
         <BTableColumn>
           <BTable>
             <ChargesTable> at src/components/workdays/ChargesTable.vue
               <BTabItem>
                 <BTabs>
                   <WorkdayListItem> at src/components/workdays/WorkdayListItem.vue
                     <Timecard> at src/components/timecards/Timecard.vue
                       <App> at src/App.vue
                         <Root> vue.esm.js:628
TypeError: _vm._ is undefined
    change ChargesTable.vue:127
    VueJS 4
    setCode CostCodeField.vue:108
    VueJS 12
    mutations timecards.js:322
    mutations timecards.js:319
    wrappedMutationHandler vuex.esm.js:844
    commitIterator vuex.esm.js:466
    commit vuex.esm.js:465
    _withCommit vuex.esm.js:624
    commit vuex.esm.js:464
    boundCommit vuex.esm.js:409
    submit CostCodeLookup.vue:134
    submit CostCodeLookup.vue:16
    VueJS 33
```

Comment: It's possible to expose Lodash globally to all components. The actual problem with Lodash is that you try to put the logic that involves it into the template, while it belongs to script part. Putting the code beyond the bare minimum to a template is a bad practice. This separation of concerns is weaker in React due to the nature of JSX. Btw the problem with debounced handler would be the same there too.

Comment: Reading the answers below i understand the issue now  - but as a personal developer preference i prefer to expose nothing globally and to call everything explicitly for clarity in every file, I find that it makes bug hunting much easier since every file is treated as its own container. If something is screwed up you dont need to hunt through 200 files and a error stack that sometimes lies to find the bug. The cost is just being more verbose. But since as developers we read code way more than we write code, to me the tradeoff is worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Accessing `_` in template

Assuming you're using the Options API, importing `_` does not automatically make it available to the template (as @tao pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72455335/6277151)). The template can only access fields exposed via the component options (e.g., `data`, `props`, `methods`, `computed`, etc.) in addition to a few allow-listed globals ([Vue 2 allowed globals](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.14/src/core/instance/proxy.js#L9), [Vue 3 allowed globals](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/9c304bfe7942a20264235865b4bb5f6e53fdee0d/packages/shared/src/globalsWhitelist.ts#L3)).

### Using `_.debounce`

`_.debounce`'s first argument is a *function reference*:

```js
_.debounce(submit(props.row, props.index), 100) // ❌ calls `submit()`, and passes the result to _.debounce()
```

To create a debounced `submit`, pass the `submit`-reference as an argument to `_.debounce` like this:

```js
_.debounce(submit, 100)
```

You technically could invoke the debounced function immediately:

```js
_.debounce(submit, 100)(props.row, props.index)
```

...but *don't do that* in the template (see reason below).

### Using a debounced event handler for `v-on`

When the value of the `v-on` directive (`@` for shorthand) is an expression (as in your case), the template compiler automatically wraps the expression in a function, so this:

```js
@change="_.debounce(submit, 100)"
```

...essentially becomes:

```js
@change="($event) => _.debounce(submit, 100)"
```

...which would have no effect, since `debounce` doesn't invoke the wrapped function itself.

You might be tempted to call the function immmediately in:

```js
@change="_.debounce(submit, 100)(props.row, props.index)"
```

...but that creates a *new* debounced function on every event, which defeats the debouncing.

### Solution

Create a debounced function in the `<script>` part of the SFC that could then be used as the `v-on` value:

*Options API:*

```html
<script>
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

export default {
  created() {
    this.debouncedSubmit = debounce(this.submit, 100)
  },
  methods: {
    submit(row, index) {/*...*/}
  }
}
</script>
```

*Composition API in `setup()` option:*

```html
<script>
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

export default {
  setup() {
    const submit = (row, index) => {/*...*/}

    return {
      debouncedSubmit: debounce(submit, 100),
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

*Composition API in `<script setup>`:*

```html
<script setup>
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

const submit = (row, index) => {/*...*/}
const debouncedSubmit = debounce(submit, 100)
</script>
```

*Template:*

```html
<cost-code-field @change="debouncedSubmit(props.row, props.index)" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-debounced-method-in-template?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FCompCompositionAPIScriptSetup.vue)

Comment: appreciate the thorough response, that was the missing knowledge I needed

Answer (score 1):

Any var referenced in template is prefixed with `this` under the hood. Which means you can't reference global vars in the template, unless they're expressly declared in its context.

Simply put, the template context is an object. If you don't define a particular key and don't assign it a particular value, it's going to be `undefined`.

Probably the most concise way of exposing globals to the template is using `computed`:

```js
// ...
  computed: {
    _: () => _
  }
// ...
```

---

In Composition API, the simplest way to expose globals is to add them  in the object returned by `setup`:

```js
export default {
  // ... 
  setup() {
    //...
    return {
      _,
      //...
    }
  }
}
```